# How to make the code server ip agnostic in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, configure, web-development-server

Whenever I restart my server IP changes, that force me to change the IP address in the code so that it works properly. I want to make the server IP agnostic, so that I don't have to change the IP in my code everytime I restart my server.

Comment: Did your client and server reside on same machine?

Comment: Tell your machine to use a static IP, or use relative urls in your code

Comment: what does your code look like? you're possibly doing it wrong - but as you've given no indication of what the server software (not the hardware) is (node, php+apache, something else) then it's a bit tricky to answer

Comment: @ataur-rahman-munna No, right now both are on different system. how does it matter? Like may be in future I want to deploy it on Cloud. So, I am just trying to ask how it matters?

Comment: @JaromandaX I am not sure. I was doing it like that because i wanted to, but now I want to develop it in the way i specified above. Right now I am using something like this:
`baseUrl : "http://IPaddress/"`
 it is static now. I want to make it dynamic, so that I don't have to update IP address of baseURL everytime. I hope it clears things a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Making the URL relative is the best solution here. And that's what I did and it worked for me.
For example:
Create a new HTMl file(index.html):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>   
  </head>
    <body>
    make the server IP agnostic
    </body>
</html>
```

Your Javascript file(script.js):

```
var baseUrl;  //global variable, so that you can use it in your large codebase later.
$.getJSON('config.json',function(data){
baseUrl = data.url;
console.log(baseUrl);
});
```

Your JSON File(Config.json):

```
{
"url": "192.120.12.1/"
}
```

And it will work. Now when ever you want you can change the url directly in you config.json file.